# Angular custom control invalid event

Tags: angular, validation, controls, customization

I created custom primeng calendar condrol. I mean, I create own component which has p-calendar inside. I cannot manage one issue. When I put my control in some another component form, and into this another component writing: this.form.myCustomCalendarControl.setErrors(...) it does nothing. Calendar input is not marked with red border as invalid. Can you advise me, how I can handle setting error into my custom component and send it to p-calendar? Thank you!

```
...

@Component({
  selector: 'app-calendar',
  templateUrl: './calendar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./calendar.component.css'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      multi: true,
      useExisting: CalendarComponent
    }]
})
export class CalendarComponent implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor {

  @Input() required: boolean = false;
  ...

  form: FormGroup;
  currentUtcDateTime: Date;

    constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.setCurrentUtcDateTime();
    this.setupForm();
  }
  

  onChange: (val: string) => void = () => {
  };

  onTouched = () => {
  };

  onInput(event: any) {
    this.inputEvent.emit(event);
  }

  onSelect(event: any) {
    this.selectEvent.emit(event);
  }

  onClear(event: any) {
    this.clearEvent.emit(event);
  }

  writeValue(value: string): void {
    this.form.reset();
    if (value) {
      this.setCalendarValue(value);
    }
    markFormGroupAsDirty(this.form);
  }

  setCurrentUtcDateTime() {
    if (isEmpty(this.form?.get('calendarValue').value)) {
      this.currentUtcDateTime = currentUtcDateTime();
    }
  }

  registerOnChange(onChange: any): void {
    this.onChange = onChange;
  }

  registerOnTouched(onTouched: any): void {
    this.onTouched = onTouched;
  }

  private setCalendarValue(value: string) {
    this.form.setValue({
      calendarValue: value
    });
  }

  private setupForm() {
    const validatorRequired = (this.required) ? Validators.required : null;
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      calendarValue: [null, validatorRequired]
    });
    this.form.valueChanges
      .pipe(debounceTime(FORM_UPDATE_DEBOUNCE_TIME))
      .subscribe(formValues => {
        this.onChange(formValues.calendarValue);
      });
  }

}
```

```
const error = {validToBeforeValidFrom: true};
customCalendarControl.setErrors(error);
```